# How do I kill specific processes if their etime is greater than X amount of time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to take the output of a `ps axo uname,pid,etime,time,cmd` and kill all related processes with an etime>=10

I need to kill pids only for on specific users which are stored in a separate file, users.txt

Basically, I want to see all my columns and I want to find all php{5,54} processes that belong to specific users, stored in a file, and kill those processes if the execution time is over ten minutes. (kill -9 not needed)

Example ps output:

```
username   574        01:37 00:00:18 /ramdisk/bin/php54 /home/username/public_html/index.php
usernum2  1367        10:28 00:00:16 /ramdisk/bin/php54 /home/usernum2/public_html/index.php
user3     3971   1-04:17:31 00:00:14 /ramdisk/bin/php54 /home/user3/public_html/index.php
usernum4  9130     14:05:32 00:00:29 /ramdisk/bin/php54 /home/usernum4/public_html/index.php
username  9189   1-01:31:12 00:00:25 /ramdisk/bin/php54 /home/username/public_html/index.php
```

My thought has been to put the ps output into a file (say procs.txt), and then grep through that.
EG:

`ps axo uname,pid,etim,time,cmd | grep 'php5' | tee procs.txt`

I could have two separate lines: one that says if column 3 is more than 5 characters kill the pid, which is easy, and then another with something like the following, but that doesn't leave me with the related pids, so I can't kill them:

`for i in $( cat users.txt ); do grep $i procs.txt | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F: '{print $(NF-1)}' | awk '$1>=10{print $1}'; done`

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/181503) probably is what you want.

Comment: I did see that in my previous searching. It assumes a static value though ("page.py" in their example), but mine changes and needs to be reformatted. EG: 1-04:17:31 vs 10:28. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: For anyone with this same question on Fedora, they can use ps with etimes (seconds) which allows an easier if >= ... Unfortunately I'm on CentOS and cannot install procps-ng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a solution in `bash`.

To find all processes that match `php5` or `php54`, for users in a file, I would use the `U` option to `ps` and `egrep`:

```
ps xo uname,pid,etim,time,cmd U"$(echo $(< users.txt))" | egrep '/php54? '
```

The `U` option will only display the processes that belong to the supplied list of users. The `<` is a shell builtin for `cat`, and the use of `echo` flattens the file entries into a single line that the `ps` command expects.

`'/php54? '` indicates that the `4` is optional, and the space at the end makes sure it doesn't match (for example) `php52`. `egrep` uses regular expressions, so it allows the use of the `?` meta character.

The output of this command can then be processed line by line with a `while read`:

```
ps xo uname,pid,etim,time,cmd U"$(echo $(< users.txt))" | egrep '/php54? ' \
| while read a
  do cols=($a)
     elapsed=${cols[2]}
     if [ ${#elapsed} -gt 5 ]
     then kill ${cols[1]}
     elif [ ${elapsed%%:*} -gt 9 ]
     then kill ${cols[1]}
     fi
  done
```

`cols` gets an array assignment, splitting the line `a` on whitespace boundaries. USER is in `cols[0]`, PID in `cols[1]`, and ELAPSED is in `cols[2]`. The PID is killed if the string length of ELAPSED is greater than 5 (indicating an elapsed time of at least an hour), or if the minutes field is greater than 9 (an elapsed time of at least 10 minutes). The `%%` expansion operator does a longest match suffix removal.

The solution can be compacted by `read`-ing directly into the relevant fields:

```
ps xo uname,pid,etim,time,cmd U"$(echo $(< users.txt))" | egrep '/php54? ' \
| while read user pid elapsed rest_of_line
  do if [ ${#elapsed} -gt 5 ]
     then kill $pid
     elif [ ${elapsed%%:*} -gt 9 ]
     then kill $pid
     fi
  done
```

Comment: If you have a users file separated only with newlines, you can use this, the way of `echo` doesn't work on my system: `"$(< users.txt  tr '\n' ','|sed 's/,$//')"`

Comment: I see now its a slight typo `etim` not `etime`, if you change that it works for me now - I didn't notice it before and I typed in my own command.

Comment: Brilliant, brilliant! That works perfectly. Thank you very much :) (And, without knowing it, your answer made something else I was working on much more simple. It's like... Christmas all over again!)